# logistic function ec90

Tags: logistic

In the following form of the logistic function:
$y_t = A + \frac{K-A}{1+exp(-B(t-M))}$ we know that M corresponds to the time that leads to a 50% maximal response also known as EC50. How can I find the EC90 corresponding to a 90% maximal response? Can I only infer it after inferring EC50?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know A, K, B, and M, and that by EC90, you mean the response 90% of the way from A (the minimum response) to K (the maximum response), then you just need to solve for the $t$ such that

$y_t = A + 0.9 (K-A)$

i.e.

$0.9 = \frac{1}{1 + \exp(-B(t-M))}$

$1 + \exp(-B(t-M)) = \frac{1}{0.9}$

$\exp(-B(t-M)) = \frac{1}{9}$

$B(t-M) = \ln(9)$

$t = M + \frac{\ln(9)}{B}$

Side note: If we'd started from

$y_t = A + 0.5 (K-A)$

you can verify that we'd have found $t=M$, i.e. that EC50 = $M$.

As to your second question: EC90 is a function of $M$ and $B$, and $M$ and EC50 are identical.  So if you haven't "inferred" EC50, you don't know $M$ and can't find EC90.  But you also need to know $B$.